# Updating app store error - Launch storyboard not found

Tags: ios, launch-screen

My app has been in the app store for 6 months and I am now trying to publish an update and I am getting an error when I validate the app.

Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify the launch storyboard filename without a filename extension for the key UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist.  The only change I made was a formula.

Comment: Does your app use a launch storyboard or launch images or both?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this I am currently also battling with this issue

Answer (score 5):

Add `Launch.storyboard` to Target Membership

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's the one really easy to get overlooked.