# iOS Application Loader: ERROR ITMS-90705: “Launch storyboard not found…”?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

> ERROR ITMS-90705: "Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify
>   the launch storyboard filename without a filename extension for the
>   key UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist."

I have my custom screen like

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key> 
<string>Splash</string>.
```

Comment: Does `Splash.storyboard` exists in your project?

Comment: No i didn't add .storyboard.I wrote only Splash.

Comment: You need to add `Splash.storyboard` in your project to make it work.

Comment: Hello Richie Rich its not working again i found same error ERROR ITMS-90705: "Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify the launch storyboard filename without a filename extension for the key UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist."

Comment: Can you share any demo project?

Comment: Nope sorry,  
but my entry screen is not LaunchScreen.storyboard.Ihave created a custom class (To show a animated splash screen. And i put class name Splash). that' s why i  am putting Splash <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key> <string>Splash</string>

Comment: Dont think its possible with splash screen.

Comment: How can you say it is not possible. if it is not then how to many app using Animation splash screen.

Comment: Its custom screens after splash page

Comment: but if you check uber app there is a animation screen in place of splash.

Comment: Check this great tutorial for that: https://www.raywenderlich.com/133224/how-to-create-an-uber-splash-screen and download their final project and analyse it. That will help you to understand.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding Splash.storyboard to target membership   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602741/updating-app-store-error-launch-storyboard-not-found/48916757#48916757

Answer (score 0):

In my project make by Xamarim.Forms,

I comment this line

```html
 <!--<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
 <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>-->
```

Best regards,